# xpath | replace with 'any'

Tags: xpath, path

I am trying to create a Distill alert and have used the field selector to create the following code. I am trying to exclude the following field from the page comparison:

`/div[contains(@class,'MUxGbd')]/span[contains(@class,'MUxGbd')]`

This code is the same throughout the page, but the path changes for each result.

How can I modify the code to be 'any' path - for example:

`//div[@id='rso']/**any**/div[contains(@class,'MUxGbd')]/span[contains(@class,'MUxGbd')]`

Thanks,

```
{
  "selections": [
    {
      "frames": [
        {
          "index": 0,
          "excludes": [
            {
              "type": "xpath",
              "expr": "//div[@id='rso']/div[@class='hlcw0c']/div[@class='g']//div[@class='tF2Cxc']/div[@class='IsZvec']/div[contains(@class,'MUxGbd')]/span[contains(@class,'MUxGbd')]"
            },
            {
              "type": "xpath",
              "expr": "//div[@id='rso']/div[@class='g']//div[@class='tF2Cxc']/div[@class='IsZvec']/div[contains(@class,'MUxGbd')]/span[contains(@class,'MUxGbd')]"
            }
          ],
          "includes": [
            {
              "type": "xpath",
              "expr": "//div[@id='rso']"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "dynamic": true,
      "delay": 0
    }
  ],
  "ignoreEmptyText": true,
  "includeStyle": false,
  "dataAttr": "text"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "path" changes for each result? What path? Would be nice to see the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried

```
"//div[@id='rso']//div[contains(@class,'MUxGbd')]/span[contains(@class,'MUxGbd')]"
```

?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That seems to have done the job.

Comment: It says I need to have at least 15 reputation before I can up vote your response.

Comment: But you still can accept the answer even with reputation of 1.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the 'tick' below the voting arrows.